# Setters Causeing Segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, this, setter

I'm sort of new to the computer coding world so I'm not exactly sure how to read the GDP, but I get Seg Fault: 11 when it tried to run my setters inside of my program. Could anyone explain why these setters are causing issues (both in lamens terms and tech terms if possible)? The setters are coded as follows:

```
class MapEntry{
private:
    int mIDVal;
    char* mKeyName;

public:
    MapEntry(char *key, int val) {
        mKeyName = key;
        mIDVal = val;
    }
    int getVal(){
        return mIDVal;
    }
    char* getKey(){
        return mKeyName;
    }
    void setVal(int val){
        this->mIDVal = val;
    }
    void setKey(char* key){
        this->mKeyName = key;
    }
};
```

I'm trying to create a simple database that has a char string as the key and a student ID of sorts as the val. Here is the rest of the code.

```
Map::Map() {
database = new MapEntry*[DATABASE_SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < DATABASE_SIZE; i++){
    database[i]->setVal(0);
    database[i]->setKey("");
    }
}

/* Adds (inserts) val with the associated key.
 * Returns if successful or not.  (It is not successful if we are out of
 * memory, or if the key already exists.)
 */
bool Map::add(const char *key, int val) {
    char lettersForKey[50];
    strcpy(lettersForKey, key); //because const ref and all that jazz

// when adding, I need to make sure the key does not already exist
    for (int i = 0; i < DATABASE_SIZE; i++)
        if (database[i]->getVal() == 0) {
            database[i]->setVal(val);
            database[i]->setKey(lettersForKey);
        }
    return false;
}

void Map::print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < DATABASE_SIZE; i++)
        if (database[i] != NULL) {
            std::cout << database[i]->getKey() << " " << database[i]->getVal() << "\n";
        }
}
```

Comment: When the code execution leaves `Map::add`, the key set for `database[i]` contains dangling pointer, pointing to invalidated memory.

Comment: On a side note, you should probably be using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use `this->` to access member variables (except when your member variables have the same name as parameters).

Comment: Throw away the book that is telling you to jump in and use `char *` as string data.  As others have stated, use `std::string`.

Comment: You could use `std::map<std::string, int>` and avoid all of these issues.

Answer (score 5):

The errors are because you haven't created any `MapEntry` objects.

This line creates an array of MapEntry *pointers*, but the pointers have not been initialised.

```
database = new MapEntry*[DATABASE_SIZE];
```

You need to create the `MapEntry` objects as well, perhaps like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < DATABASE_SIZE; i++){
    database[i] = new MapEntry();
    database[i]->setVal(0);
    database[i]->setKey("");
    }
}
```

Of course you could avoid all the trouble by avoiding pointers, you do know that they are bad?

```
class Map
{
    std::vector<MapEntry> database;
};

Map::Map() : database(DATABASE_SIZE)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DATABASE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        database[i].setVal(0);
        database[i].setKey("");
    }
}
```

No pointers, no problems. You should replace the `char* mKeyName` pointer in `MapEntry` with `std::string mKeyName` too.

Comment: Or better yet, make `database` an array of `MapEntry` *objects* instead of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
database[i]->setKey(lettersForKey);
```

you make the `mKeyName` member point to the first element of an array that is ***local*** inside the `Map::add` function. As soon as the `Map::add` function exits that array goes out of scope (and basically cease to exist), and will leave you with an invalid pointer. Dereferencing that pointer will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

If you want to handle strings, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.